# client.get_user() isn't working in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I've been trying to get a user object from an ID, but it returns "NoneType". Here is my code:

```
user = client.get_user(INT)
```

Client is defined in my code as:

```
client = discord.Client()
```

EDIT:
INT would be replaced with a valid ID, which I have done in my actual code

Comment: This is an intents issue, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64398647/14196628)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Bot - Guild Members Showing in count... but not in guild.members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397965/discord-bot-guild-members-showing-in-count-but-not-in-guild-members)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a member object, your bot need members intent, which is disabled by default. To get it you have to do two things:

1. Go to the developer portal and under 'bot' ==> 'Privileged Gateway Intents' toggle 'SERVER MEMBERS INTENT' to be on.
2. Enable it in your client, like:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```