# Trying to fetch all members in a guild(discord.py rewrite)

Tags: discord.py

Here is my code:

```
@bot.command()
async def list(ctx):
  guild = ctx.guild
  members = '\n - '.join([member.name for member in guild.fetch_members])
  await ctx.send(f'Guild Members:\n - {members}')
```

I have also tried guild.members but does not work, here is the error

```
The Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable. Please, use a valid command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list` is keyword in python, try not to use it for user-defined function.

Here is the code you can use to fetch members with serial number:

```
@bot.command()
async def memberlist(ctx):
    members = ''
    for index, member in enumerate(ctx.guild.members, start=1):
        members += f'{index}) {member}\n'
    await ctx.send(members)
```

Comment: Hi! I tried this but it only lists the bot, this happened to me before? Anyway to fix this?

Comment: It's working for me, can you tell me what error are you getting now?

Comment: @PandaDev Make sure you've enabled the [members intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397965/discord-bot-guild-members-showing-in-count-but-not-in-guild-members/64398647#64398647), both in your code and through Discord's web interface.

Comment: @CrazyChucky How do I enable it through my code

Comment: Follow the link, and look at the code samples in A Primer to Gateway Intents.